# C programming, make change at two location with one macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
struct Error
{
   MACRO(1, Connect);
   MACRO(2, Timeout);
};
```

I need to define MACRO() in such way that the above code will generate the following code.

```
struct Error
{  
   static const int Connect = 1;
   static const int Timeout = 2;
   const char * const name[] = {"Connect", "Timeout"};
};
```

Is this possible or what is the alternative to get what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this but it will be so convoluted I would not recommend it. What is your bigger goal? Why do you want this? Seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do cannot be achieved with macros.

Comment: Use [XMacro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro)

Comment: @MohitJain Thanks for the link. I've been using this for quite some time, but I never knew it had a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want, is to have a single list, that will automatically generate the definition and the name list, correct?

If so, search for X Macros in google.

Example:

```
#define EXPAND_AS_DEFINITION(a, b) static const int b = a;
#define EXPAND_AS_ARRAY(a, b) #b,

#define STATE_TABLE(ENTRY)  \
   ENTRY(1, Connect)       \
ENTRY(2, Timeout)   

struct Error
{       
   STATE_TABLE(EXPAND_AS_DEFINITION)
   static const char * const name[];      
};

const char * const Error::name[] = {STATE_TABLE(EXPAND_AS_ARRAY) 0};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly, but you can if you move the macros to a separate location (such as a separate file):

**macros.hpp**

```
MACRO(1, Connect)
MACRO(2, Timeout)

#undef MACRO
```

**the other file**

```
struct Error
{
  #define MACRO(a, b) static const int b = a;
  #include "macros.hpp"

  const char * const name [] = {
  #define MACRO(a, b) #b,
  #include "macros.hpp"
  }
};
```

Alternatively, you could achieve a similar effect with [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Comment: This is generally the right solution.  If the number is used to lookup the name, then I'd use an Enum to autogenerate a correct array index: `#define MACRO(a, b) b##_Offset,` and `enum { #include "macros.hpp" };`  That way the array index is programmatically independent of how many macros are used.  `if (error==Connect) log_error(name[Connect_Offset]);` But maybe you don't need that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) solution:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/size.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>

#define FIRST(a, b) a
#define SECOND(a, b) b

#define DECLARE_VAR(r, data, elem)              \
    static const int FIRST elem = SECOND elem;

#define NAME_ARRAY_ELEM(r, data, elem)          \
    BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(FIRST elem), 

#define MACRO(seq)                                      \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(DECLARE_VAR, ~, seq)          \
    const char * const name[] = {                       \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(NAME_ARRAY_ELEM, ~, seq)  \
    }

int main()
{
    MACRO(((Connect, 1))((TimeOut, 2)));
    return 0;
}
```

You have to make sure to double bracket each ((Token, value)) pair, however you don't need a separate file for your macro.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like like you are trying to define an `enum Error` that also has the strings as members. I will give you my own solution to this problem. (I'm not addressing the question but I  believe that my answer is relevant for what I understand that OP is trying to do.)

And I just realized that OP is targeting C, not C++, so not sure if this can be done...

In `MyEnum.hpp`

```
#define MYENUM(X,...)                                        \
    struct X {                                               \
        enum Enum {__VA_ARGS__};                             \
        static const std::vector<std::string> names;         \
        static X::Enum which(const std::string& s) {         \ 
            return static_cast<X::Enum>(findEnum(s,names));  \
        }                                                    \
        static std::string str(X::Enum i) {                  \ 
            return names[i];}                                \
    }
```

Here `findEnum()` is just a linear search over the vector that returns the position index (additionally, in my implementation if it doesn't find it it throws an exception with all the possible correct inputs, I also do case insensitive comparison). Note that an ordered map instead of a vector would be more efficient (O(log(n)) instead of O(n)), but I didn't cared much because the size of those things is very small in my case.

Below the previous macro, declare your enum as

```
MYENUM(Error,Connect,Timeout); // I put the semicolon here not in the macro
```

And in `MyEnum.cpp`, add

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

const std::vector<std::string> Error::names = boost::assign::list_of
("Connect")("Timeout");
```

(I think that it should be possible to use initialization lists with a modern compiler). The important thing here is to make sure that the order is the same, otherwise it will not  work.

Then, you can do stuff like this:

```
Error::Enum err1 = Error::Connect;
Error::Enum err2 = Error::which("Timeout");
std::cout << "Got " << Error::str(err1) << " error. Not good.\n";
```